# How to Apply Bootstrap on Dropdown list on MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to insert bootstrap in the dropdown list using Razor's `@Html.DropDownListFor()` in MVC but I didn't get the right answers(I searched for some answers but there they used form-control as the class) I want to use dropdown as a class in bootstrap but didn't get it. So hoping to get the answers here.

[I am trying to get bootstrap for select tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S70S4.jpg)

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: Are you trying to get the bootstrap dropdown style for <select> ?

Comment: @Win I have edited question with picture of my code

Comment: @Pradeep yes also take a look at the picture i edited in question

Comment: @Darkness always embed your code in your question as it will be more easier for the others to understand  no need to attach an image of the code.

Comment: @faisal1208 Thanks will do next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is no default style by Bootstrap for select tag. Refer [boostrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/) do the code change as below.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Id, Model.Values, new { @class = "selectpicker" })
```

Comment: so selectpicker is a bootstrap class ? Because i couldn't find selectpicker in bootstrap file

Comment: It is part of the link I have given above bootstrap-select. So you have to add file reference in your project.